# Linq query explained in plain english

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query I'm not 100% sure of, can someone explain it in plain English what is happening

```
var duplicates = this.BedStays
                  .GroupBy(i => new { i.PatientClassificationCode, i.BedBandCode, i.BedLevelAddOnInd, i.ServiceCodeTypeCode, i.ServiceCode, i.DayRate })
                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for edit

Answer (score 2):

It will give you all duplicate rows which have the same

- PatientClassificationCode
- BedBandCode
- BedLevelAddOnInd
- ServiceCodeTypeCode
- ServiceCode
- DayRate

It does this by grouping rows together which have the same criteria, and then only displaying the groups with more than one row (that is, duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

```
var duplicates = this.BedStays
```

...Assigning to a var called "duplicates" from a property in this class called "BedStays."

```
.GroupBy(
```

...Grouping by a set of specific traits...

```
i =>
```

Called a single BedStay "i" (could have called it instead "aBedStay" or "bedStay" but the author went with "i")...

```
 new { i.PatientClassificationCode, i.BedBandCode, i.BedLevelAddOnInd, i.ServiceCodeTypeCode, i.ServiceCode, i.DayRate })
```

...Creating a new object to sort by (First by the first member, then by the second, and so on and so forth)...

```
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
```

...Only picking the bedStay groupings where there's at least one matching member (I believe this is unneeded as all groupings, by definition, will only exist if from at least one grouping definition)...

```
.Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

...And finally we're only caring about the key, which is the grouping we defined when we new'd up the {i.Property, i.Property, i.Property} object. And we make it a list.

Comment: more than one matching member.. > 1

Answer (score 0):

> can someone explain it in plain English what is happening

Query is primarily listing all duplicates in your `BedStays` collection,  by grouping on `PatientClassificationCode, BedBandCode, BedLevelAddOnInd, ServiceCodeTypeCode, ServiceCode, DayRate` fields.

Comment: thanks everyone, thats what I thought, but have never seen a linq query constructed that way

Comment: Usually that is approach for finding the duplicates, similar to sql :-)